# Javascript local storage error

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

How can I assign to a JavaScript variable a local storage variable?

Here is my attempt:

```
var abc=localStorage.crabc;
function tab()
{
    if (abc==2) {
        window.open("index.html","_self")
    } else {
        window.open("main.html","_self")
    }
}
tab()
localStorage.crabc="2";
```

Comment: in you code, you have putted `localStorage.crabc="2";` line after `tab()`, This may be the reason:), what is the error?

Comment: `if (abc = 2)`? I would advise (re)visiting js fundamentals...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`localStorage.getItem()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#dom-storage-getitem) and [`localStorage.setItem()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#dom-storage-setitem) to retrieve and store items to localStorage:

```
var abc=localStorage.getItem('crabc');

function tab()
{
    if (abc=='2') {
        window.open("index.html","_self")
    } else {
        window.open("main.html","_self")
    }
}
tab();
localStorage.setItem('crabc', '2');
```

Comment: OMG that worked.Thank you very very much MrCode.Will this local storage variable will remain forever on PC or will it get removed when user uses something like Ccleaner?Thank you very much again!!!

Comment: It will remain until the user specifically deletes it. I'm not sure if the current version of CCleaner deletes local storage, but the user can delete it from the browser options if they want.

Comment: Just tried myself it remains even after using it thank you very much for clarifying!!!

Answer (score 3):

1. The item in localStorage is going to be a string.
2. You're using the assignment operator - one equal sign: "=" - as opposed to the equals operator "==".
3. You're missing a semicolon after `tab()`

Comment: Sorry im beginner.What i need with this code is when an user visits for the first time a particular url he/she should be redirected to some url from second time to infinite time he should go on to second url.Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Try this [Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/NLawC/)

```
 function tab() {
        var check = window.localStorage.getItem("visitedBefore");

        if (check) {
            alert('already visited');
            window.open("index.html", "_self")
        } else {
            alert('first time visited');
            window.open("main.html", "_self")
        }

        window.localStorage.setItem("visitedBefore", true);
    }
```

HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="redirect" onclick="tab()" />
```

Comment: Hi Mota chuha my reputation level is 8 so i need to go to 15 to upvote once.